# flutter Sorting list of map

Tags: flutter, dart

so i want to make rating box like the image below, but for the rating value it hasn't been sorted yet, plus it's not int/double but string. What code is suitable for this ?

i want it to result High rating 5 to lowest 1

i will be glad if you give some example code

don't mind the linear progress bar

[image]

json data

```
"all_rating": [
                {
                    "rating": "1",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "2",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "4",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "4.5",               
                },
                {
                    "rating": "5",
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sorting system helps you to get your solution.

```
List<Map> allRating = [
                {
                    "rating": "1",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "2",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "4",
                },
                {
                    "rating": "4.5",               
                },
                {
                    "rating": "5",
                }
            ];
  
allRating.sort((a, b) => (b['rating']).compareTo(a['rating'])); /// sort List<Map<String,dynamic>>

print(allRating);  /// output -> [{rating: 5}, {rating: 4.5}, {rating: 4}, {rating: 2}, {rating: 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `double.parse(<any string containing double>)` to convert string to double and then sort accordingly.

To sort, custom compare to function needs to be given

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.rating.compareTo(b.rating));
```

Comment: that's the question, how to sort it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double.parse(<any string containing double>)` to convert string to double and then sort them like below.

```
// this is list of double that you got from map.
List<double> doubleList = [1,0.5,4,3,2];

// sort the list using sort function.
doubleList.sort();
```